# Pull Requests on Google Cloud Source Repos

Tags: google-cloud-source-repos

Is Google planning to enable pull requests on google cloud repos? We love using these repos in GCP but need to use pull requests in our development process  (frankly, we're surprised and curious why they are not enabled). So at this point we are wondering if we need to migrate or if they are planning to add this feature.